# Sharepoint NPM installed but Visual Studio dont recognize it

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, npm, sharepoint

I'm doing a project in TypeScript using visual studio 2019. Since the last git branch merging, Visual Studio underline in red every functions coming from the [Sharepoint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sharepoint) npm.
However, the npm package is correctly installed (i guess) and up to date.
Here's a copy of my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "solution-ticketing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "SolutionTicketing",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.24",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.5",
    "@types/sharepoint": "^2016.1.8",
    "browserify": "^16.5.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-spsave": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "source": "0.0.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And a copy of my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [
    "src/*.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "dom", "es6" ],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "Ticketing"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

When I compile with Gulp there's no error.